# Rails preview update associations without saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to preview what the model will look like when saved without currently saving to the database.

I am using `@event.attributes =` because that assigns but does not save attributes for `@event` to the database.

However, when I also try to assign the `audiences` association, Rails inserts new records into the `audiences_events` join table.  Not cool.  Is there a way to preview what these new associations will look like without inserting into the join table?

## Model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :audiences # And vice versa for the Audience model.
end
```

## Controller

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController 

  def preview
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @event.attributes = event_params
  end

  private
    def event_params
      params[:event].permit(:name, :start_time, :audiences => [:id, :name]
    end

end
```

## Possible Solutions?

Possible solutions that I thought of, but don't know how to do:

- Using some sort of method that assigns associations, but does not persist them.
- disabling all database writes for this one action (I dont know how to do that).
- Rolling back all database changes at the end of this action

Any help with these would be great!

**UPDATE:**
After the reading the great answers below, I ended up writing this service class that assigns the non-nested attributes to the Event model, then calls collection.build on each of the nested params.  I made a little gist.  Happy to receive comments/suggestions.

https://gist.github.com/jameskerr/69cedb2f30c95342f64a

Comment: If you do `Event.new(name: 'some name').audiences.build(name:c 'some audience')` without calling save, the Event and Audience records are not supposed to be stored in the DB (calling `.persisted?` on each record should return `false`) (but I am curious about the join record, the one containing the Event id and the Audience id)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In these [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) you have:

> When are Objects Saved?
>
> When you assign an object to a has_and_belongs_to_many association, that object is automatically saved (in order to update the join table). If you assign multiple objects in one statement, then they are all saved.
>
> If you want to assign an object to a has_and_belongs_to_many association without saving the object, use the `collection.build` method.

Here is a good answer for Rails 3 that goes over some of the same issues

[Rails 3 has_and_belongs_to_many association: how to assign related objects without saving them to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491920/rails-3-has-and-belongs-to-many-association-how-to-assign-related-objects-witho)

Comment: Thanks! So it looks like I will have to have a line that explicitly builds each association.

Answer (score 4):

### Transactions

Creating [transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) is pretty straight forward:

```
Event.transaction do
  @event.audiences.create!
  @event.audiences.first.destroy!
end
```

Or

```
@event.transaction do
  @event.audiences.create!
  @event.audiences.first.destroy!
end
```

Notice the use of the "bang" methods `create!` and `destroy!`, unlike `create` which returns false `create!` will raise an exception if it fails and cause the transaction to rollback.

You can also manually trigger a rollback anywhere in the a transaction by raising `ActiveRecord::Rollback`.

### Build

`build` instantiates a new related object without saving.

```
event = Event.new(name: 'Party').audiences.build(name: 'Party People')
event.save # saves both event and audiences
```

Comment: Which you use depends on your needs - if you need to guarantee that any callbacks are successful or database constraints (such as unique indices) are met than you want transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a pretty old question, but I found a solution that works perfectly for me and hope it could save time to someone else:

```
class A
  has_many :bs, class_name 'B'
end

class B
  belongs_to :a, class_name: 'A'
end

a.bs.target.clear
new_bs.each {|new_b| a.bs.build new_b.attributes.except('created_at', 'updated_at', 'id') }
```

you will avoid autosave that Rails does when you do `a.bs = new_bs`